# New pandas dataframe column using values from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, for example:

```
colA      colB 
code1      num
code2      num
code3      num
code4      num
code5      num
```

I also have a python dictionary, for example:

```
py_dict = {'code1': [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5], 'code2': [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5], 'code3': [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5], 'code4': [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5], 'code5': [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]}
```

What I would like to do is create a new column in the pandas dataframe, call it colC, which uses the key from colA to match the corresponding key/list in py_dict and return the third list value, val3.  I've experimented with dataframe.from_dict() and dataframe.update() but not sure how to index the dictionary properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new dict containing only the value you want from each list:

```
new_dict = {k: v[2] for k, v in py_dict.iteritems()}
```

Then you can use `Series.map`

```
df['new_col'] = df.colA.map(new_dict)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on returning a string value for v[2] in this example?

Comment: @user2920457: What do you mean?  The question doesn't say anything about what type `val2` is.  If it's already a string, nothing to do.  If you want to convert `v[2]` to a string, do `str(v[2])` inside the `new_dict` comprehension.

Comment: You're correct. The mistake was with using wrong df column name for map(), my bad.